# Close Window from mywindow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my files

```
index.php
pwd.php
common.js
```

In the `index.php`  i am opening a file `pwd.php` as mywindow and i wanted to close it by pressing a button in the My Window. How can i do this ?

`index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="openWin()">Open w3schools.com in a new window</button>
<?php 
include ('common.js');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

'pwd.php'

```
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close the new window (w3schools.com)</button>
<?php 
include ('common.js');
?>
```

`common.js`

```
<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("pwd.php", "_blank", "width=500, height=500");
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

When i try to close i am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined` in the console of the `pwd.php` .

What is the mistake i am doing an How can i achieve it ?

**Note :**

I don't want to call the `closeWin()` from the Parent window.

I want to call the `closeWin()` in any even from the myWindow that is created.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.parent.closeWin(); in close button because its inside the iframe and your function is in your parent window.

**EDIT**

Seems you misunderstood my answer

first put the code in your link like this:

'pwd.php'

```
<button onclick="window.parent.closeWin()">Close the new window (w3schools.com)</button>
```

second, don't include common.js in your pwd.php, since we will use the parent window function.

**SECOND EDIT**

You can add it in a function, but you should create different one, like this

```
<button onclick="child_closeWin()">Close the new window (w3schools.com)</button>
```

and the function should be:

```
function child_closeWin() {  
                             window.parent.closeWin(); 
                          }
```

note that this function should be added specifically inside pwd.php only and not in index.php, just add script tag inside 'pwd.php' and add the funtion.

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: like how..Can you tel me pls

Comment: Can i call this in a function ? Because i have to do it in a function and not inside the `onclick`

Comment: Same error :( `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85164/discussion-between-user4989228-and-vmcreator).